# How to get amount of token0 and token1 deposited by me using uniswap v2 API?

Tags: tokens, uniswap

Using uniswap, I want to check the amount of token0 and token1 deposited by user.
For instance, user created pair Token0/Token1 in Uniswap.
First, user input amount of Token0 and Token1.
When start trading and used user's token, the remaining amount would be changed.
(I think it seems that the remaining amount is called reserve.

If someone knows about this, please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI - The V2 API has been deprecated - calls that would have gone through the API should be directed to the Uniswap subgraph